# SAS (proc risk) - instrument statement - adding a variable to an inherited definition

Tags: sas

How do you ADD an instrument variable to an existing definition? using code?  eg:

```
proc risk;
 environment new = work.Test ;
 declare instvars=(var1 num var, var2 num var, var3 num var);
 instrument MyInst variables = ( var1, var2 ) ;
 environment save;
run;

proc risk;
 environment open= work.Test;
 instrument MyInst variables= ( /* how do I add var3? */);
 environment save;
run;
```

There must be an easy way!  If not - how can one determine the original definition (programmatically) ?

To expand on the requirement - I cannot update the original instrument definition, as this is inherited from a production environment.  Also - I do not wish to hardcode the original instrument variables in the second instrument statement, in case the original environment changes.

I think there might not be another way (other than hard coding) but open to ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got there - with a bit of help!  Without using the Risk Dimensions UI, or rewriting the instrument statement, the only other way is to use the dataset created by the WRITETYPES statement.

```
proc risk;
 environment new = work.Test ;
 declare instvars=(var1 num var, var2 num var, var3 num var);
 instrument MyInst variables = ( var1, var2 ) ;
 writetypes out=temp;
 environment save;
run;

proc sql; 
insert into temp set insttype='MyInst', type='VAR', content='VAR3';

proc sort data=temp; by _all_; run;

proc risk;
 environment open= work.Test;
 readtypes data=temp;
 environment save;
run;
```